# FMX TBitmap fastest saving of transparent image

Tags: delphi, bitmap, firemonkey

I am scaling icons (using a software scaler algorithm) and want to cache the newly resized icons by saving them to disk while preserving transparency (the alpha channel).

Calling "**Bitmap.SaveToDisk('filename.bmp')**" followed by "**Bitmap.LoadFromDisk('filename.bmp')**" strips the alpha channel.

Calling "**Bitmap.SaveToDisk('filename.png')**" followed by "**Bitmap.LoadFromDisk('filename.png')**" maintains the alpha channel but has a much higher CPU overhead due to the encoding/decoding required by the PNG format.

I'm aware I can go behind the scenes, get the scanlines and simply dump the scanline data to a file, but I was wondering if there was a more straightforward method with lower CPU utilization?

Edit #1:
I am still interested in an answer, but in the meanwhile I wrote a work-around unit that saves/loads raw ARGB data from a firemonkey TBitmap:
https://github.com/bLightZP/Save-and-Load-FMX-ARGB-Bitmap

Comment: did you try to set the bitmap pixelFormat so 32 bit ?

Comment: The bmp is saved as 32bit by default, and to clarify, this is an FMX TBitmap, not a VCL TBitmap.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually pressed to load and save those images? I mean, if you're worried about CPU overhead at PNG (de)compression, keep them as bitmaps in memory. Very frequent loading and saving anything to disk won't bring you any more performance. What's the aim behind?

Comment: The use case is multiple icons being scaled to the display device and then cached to drive.  Loading 30 png files can take a bit on android.  And the initial one-time save operation would also be faster when saving uncompressed.